# How to list available ADSI (Active Directory Service Interfaces) service providers?

Tags: .net, windows, active-directory

How can I list available [ADSI (Active Directory Service Interfaces) service providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772235%28VS.85%29.aspx)?

On [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422423/how-to-list-available-adsi-active-directory-service-interfaces-service-provider) no one knows, so they advised me to ask here.

Comment: What do you mean by list them?

Comment: think your question is self answering in this case, the list is the list as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Zoredache I mean: How to get a list of available service providers on a server? (How to write a script that will do that?)

Comment: @tony The page contains a service providers that are implemented by Microsoft, but there can be more (e.g. 3rd party) service providers installed on a server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this works, googled "script list of adsi providers"

```
WScript.Echo( listProviders() );

function listProviders()
{
    var list = "ADSI Providers on this machine\n" );
    list    += "==============================\n" );

    var ads = GetObject( "ADs:" );

    var e = new Enumerator( ads );
    for( ; !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext() )
    {
        var mem = e.item();
        list += mem.Name + "\n";    
    }
    return( list );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at KB-233023 [How To Find All ADSI Providers on a System](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/233023)
There you can find c++ version to get the list.